# Set field via class

Tags: c#, .net

For example if we have class MyClass with private field. Is it possible to set value via class object.

```
 public class MyClass { private int field; }

 public class Program
    {
      public static void Main()
      {
        MyClass cl = new MyClass();
        cl = 10; // set value
      }
    }
```

Comment: nope that violates the concept of private fields.

Comment: you could have the constructor take it as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

It's not directly possible like that in C#, but it's possible to do it through implicit operator overloading by instantiating the class from a value.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int field;

    public static implicit operator MyClass(int value)
    {
        return new MyClass { field = value };
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like:

```
MyClass myClass = 100;
```

That's the closest you will get to what you want.

Other than that you can really only do it through constructors or reflection.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can expose a method that set the value.

```
private int _field;

public void SetMyPrivateField(int val) 
{
   _field = val;
}
```

or you can take pass the value in with the constructor

```
public class MyClass 
{
   private int _field;

   public MyClass(int val) 
   {
       _field = val;
   }
}
```

Comment: An accessor method in C#?

Comment: Please use a property instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set value via class object.

It is indeed *possible* to do this using reflection:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyClass cl = new MyClass();
        var fi = cl.GetType().GetField("field", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        fi.SetValue(cl, 10);

        Console.WriteLine(fi.GetValue(cl));
    }
}
```

But there is probably a reason for the field being private so you shouldn't do this. But you *can*.

Comment: Beginning programmers ask about fundaments of OOP, Reflection is not answer

Comment: The question is tagged C# and .NET and reads "is it possible to set value...". It doesn't mention anything about OOP concepts.

Answer (score 0):

This violate Object Oriented concepts which used in C#
so, you shouldn't do that and save encapsulation concept
by using

- Property

  ```
   public Get{get=>field;set=>field=value;}
  ```
- Setter & Getter
- Constructor

  ```
  public MyClass(int field) {this.field = field;}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much encapsulation you want to use. Realistically the best way to think about this is to go for the way that limits the accessibility of the variable as much as possible.

### You want a variable/property to be read/write outside of the class

Use a public property. This gives you read and write access. There is no need for a backing variable as it's all readable/writeable anyway.

```
public MyClass
{
    public int Field {get; set;}
}
```

### You want a variable/property to be readable outside of the class, but not writeable

There is a couple of ways to skin a cat here. One way is to still use a property but make the setter private, meaning it can only be set inside the class.

```
public MyClass
{
    public int Field {get; private set;}

    public MyClass(int field)
    {
        Field = field;
    }
}
```

I prefer to have a backing readonly variable if it's only to be set inside the constructor and it will never change.

```
public MyClass
{
    private readonly int _field;
    public int Field {get=>_field;}

    public MyClass(int field)
    {
        _field = field;
    }
}
```

### You want a variable to be passed into a class but not readable/writeable from that point

You should just use a private readonly variable.

```
public MyClass
{
    private readonly int _field;

    public MyClass(int field)
    {
        _field = field;
    }
}
```